# WSO2 BAM error: ClassNotFoundException: HiveEventCounter when try to run Hive Analytics

Tags: wso2, wso2-bam

I am using WSO2 BAM 2.4.1 to run Hive Analytic scripts and run into the following error. Just wonder if there is a way to resolve this error.

> Total MapReduce jobs = 1 Launching Job 1 out of 1 Number of reduce
>   tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator log4j:ERROR Could
>   not instantiate class [org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HiveEventCounter].
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HiveEventCounter log4j:ERROR Could not
>   instantiate appender named "EventCounter"

Comment: Are your running BAM with embedded Hadoop instance or did you point BAM to an external Hadoop cluster? If so, what's the Hadoop version?

Comment: Hello, I am running BAM with the embedded Hadoop instance.

Comment: Hi John,Just want to know that you are running BAM on Linux or Windows environment?

Comment: Windows and Linux, both have the same issue.